# no data found when trying to log CAN data using a PiCAN2 and a raspberry pi

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, queue, can-bus

I'm not sure what I'm really doing here and need a little guidance to point me in the right direction with regards to CANBUS sniffing.
I am currently using a PiCAN2 (with gps and gyro) with a raspberry pi 4 to sniff the CANBUS output from a mobileye detection unit. I have the CAN output protocol  of the mobileye, the raspberry pi is set up with all the libraries installed and everything seems to be working correctly except the capture of CAN data (the logger captures GPS and all the kinematic data perfectly).
I've been going around in circles because I can't seem to find why I get very intermittent CAN data from the mobileye unit.

I am trying to get send a request to the unit and waiting for any output but am not getting anything.

I even just try to run:

`candump can0` or `cansniffer can0`  and dont get anything.

I've tried to tie directly to the vehicle CAN as well and get intermittent CAN as well.
I've soldered on a jumper to bridge JP2 to use the 120 ohm resistor but that makes the can0 interface disappear. Confirmed this using `ifconfig` and so I leave the jumper open.

I also sometimes get an sm.smBUS error message that bus.recv() does not exist?

My code is as follows:

```
from gps import *
import datetime
import sys
import smbus
import math
import time, inspect
import signal
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import can
import os
import binascii
import bitstring
from bitstring import BitArray
import threading
from threading import Thread
from can import Message

try:
    import queue
except ImportError:
    import Queue as queue

#### Bring up can0 interface at 500kbps
os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000")
time.sleep(0.1)
print('Ready')

#### define global variables
PICANGPS_PORT = "/dev/serial0"
led = 22
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(led,True)
mbdata = ''
PID_REQUEST= 0x7DF

###### ive left out some bits relating to GPS and the file name definitions

#### Communicate with CAN interface
try:
    bus = can.interface.Bus(channel='can0', bustype='socketcan_native')
except OSError:
    print('Cannot find PiCAN board.')
    GPIO.output(led,False)
    exit()

#### CAN Receive thread
def can_rx_task():  # Receive thread
    while True:
        print ('Receiving Message')
        msg = bus.recv()
        if msg.arbitration_id == MB_DISPLAY:
            q.put(msg)          # Put message into queue
            print ('Received Message!')
        if msg.arbitration_id == CAR_SIGNALS:
            q.put(msg)          # Put message into queue
            print ('Received Message!')

#### CAN Transmit thread
def can_tx_task():  # Transmit thread
    while True:
        GPIO.output(led,True)
        # Sent a Engine coolant temperature request
        msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],extended_id=False)
        bus.send(msg)
        time.sleep(0.05)
        GPIO.output(led,False)
        time.sleep(0.05)

q = queue.Queue()
rx = threading.Thread(target = can_rx_task)
rx.start()
tx = threading.Thread(target = can_tx_task)
tx.start()

#### main loop
try:
    while True:
        # create log file - timestamped 
        f=open(path+fname+".csv",'a')
        # get current timestamp
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        picantimestamp = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

        #### mobileye CAN sniff loop
        for i in range(4):
            # CAN sniff for CAN data frame
            if q.empty() != True:   # Check if there is a message in queue
                mbdata = q.get()
                c = '{0:f} {1:d} {2:x} '.format(mbdata.timestamp,count, mbdata.arbitration_id, mbdata.dlc)
                s = ''
                print ('Received CAN Message')
                for j in range(mbdata.dlc):
                    s +=  '{0:x} '.format(mbdata.data[j])
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should try to troubleshoot this?
Happy to discuss it further, I'm just a little confused and would gladly take any input.

Comment: If you are connecting to a functioning bus you will not need the termination resistor. You mentioned `candump` is not working even when connected directly to the vehicle?

Comment: thanks, yes I've tried with both the jumper that enables the resistor on and off and it still doesn't work.
candump does not yield any/intermittent can signals.
same with cansniffer.

Comment: I would recommend ensuring you can read data reliably with candump before working on your script. Connecting to pins 6 and 14 of the obd2 port yield no data? If so something is either not configured correctly or potentially damaged.

Comment: That’s the weird thing, it works intermittently. I’m connecting to a Mitsubishi so it’s in a different location but I do have the can wires. I’m also trying to connect through to a Mobileye unit that has a can output as well and I’m getting the same problem.